# I need help evaluating an integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In statistics
$$
f(r) = c \cdot \frac{(1-r^2)^{\frac n2 -2}}{(1 - \rho r)^{n- \frac 32}} \cdot F_{2,1} \!\left(\frac 12, \frac 12; n-\frac12; \frac{1+\rho r}{2} \right)
$$
is the probability density function (PDF) of a sample correlation coefficient $r$ when sampling from a bivariate normal distribution with correlation coefficient $\rho$; where $n$ is the sample size, $F_{2,1}$ is the hypergeometric function, and $c$ is the normalizing constant.  It's value is well known.

**My question**: is it possible to establish the value of the constant $c$ from
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(r) ~ dr = 1 ~?
$$
This certainly leads to a rather nontrivial integration.

Comment: For what its worth, I considered integration by parts in the hope of getting a recursion formula on the exponent in the denominator, having this exponent go towards zero.  This got ugly because of the $(1-r^2)$ in the numerator.  Further, I see no way of using the idea that $(1-r^2) = (1-r)(1+r).$  Therefore, I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

**Preamble:** *This first section is just a collection of definitions and properties of special functions that will be needed for the evaluation of our integral. Skip to the bottom for the main derivation and reference these notes as needed.*

Let $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{D}$ denote the respective subsets of the complex plane given by $\mathbb{H}:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re{\left(z\right)}>0\}\land\mathbb{D}:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.

Recall that the beta function is defined by the integral

$$\operatorname{B}{\left(x,y\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{x-1}\left(1-t\right)^{y-1};~~~\small{\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{H}^{2}},$$

and the gamma function is defined by the (convergent) improper integral

$$\Gamma{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{z-1}\exp{\left(-t\right)};~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{H}}.$$

The two functions are related to each other by the well-known identity:

$$\Gamma{\left(x\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(y\right)}=\Gamma{\left(x+y\right)}\operatorname{B}{\left(x,y\right)};~~~\small{\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{H}^{2}}.$$

The gamma function obeys the following duplication formula:

$$\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(2z\right)}=2^{2z-1}\,\Gamma{\left(z\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(z+\frac12\right)};~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}}.$$

For positive real parameters, Gauss's hypergeometric function ${_2F_1}$ is defined on the unit disk by the (convergent) infinite series

$${_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;z\right)}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a\right)_{n}\,\left(b\right)_{n}}{\left(c\right)_{n}}\cdot\frac{z^{n}}{n!};~~~\small{\left(a,b,c\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{3}\land z\in\mathbb{D}},$$

where $\left(a\right)_{n}$ denotes the Pochhammer symbol defined for positive real $a$ and nonnegative integer $n$ by

$$\left(a\right)_{n}:=\frac{\Gamma{\left(a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}};~~~\small{\left(n,a\right)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}}.$$

Similarly, Clausen's hypergeometric function ${_3F_2}$ is defined for positive real parameters on the unit disk by the (convergent) infinite series

$${_3F_2}{\left(a,b,c;p,q;z\right)}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a\right)_{n}\,\left(b\right)_{n}\,\left(c\right)_{n}}{\left(p\right)_{n}\,\left(q\right)_{n}}\cdot\frac{z^{n}}{n!};~~~\small{\left(a,b,c,p,q\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{5}\land z\in\mathbb{D}}.$$

It follows immediately from the series definitions of ${_3F_2}$ and ${_2F_1}$ that

$${_3F_2}{\left(a,b,c;c,q;z\right)}={_2F_1}{\left(a,b;q;z\right)};~~~\small{\left(a,b,c,q\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{4}\land z\in\mathbb{C}\land|z|<1}.$$

Making use of integral representations and summation under the integral sign, we can also show that

$${_2F_1}{\left(a,b;b;z\right)}=\left(1-z\right)^{-a};~~~\small{\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}\land z\in\left(-1,1\right)}.$$

*Proof:*

$$\begin{align}
{_2F_1}{\left(a,b;b;z\right)}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a\right)_{n}\,z^{n}}{n!}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}\Gamma{\left(a+n\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{a+n-1}\exp{\left(-t\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{z^{n}t^{n}}{n!}t^{a-1}\exp{\left(-t\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}t^{n}}{n!}t^{a-1}\exp{\left(-t\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{a-1}\exp{\left(zt\right)}\exp{\left(-t\right)}\\
&=\frac{(1-z)^{-a}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,(1-z)((1-z)t)^{a-1}\exp{\left(-(1-z)t\right)}\\
&=\frac{(1-z)^{-a}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,u^{a-1}\exp{\left(-u\right)};~~~\small{\left[t=\frac{u}{1-z}\right]}\\
&=\left(1-z\right)^{-a}.\\
\end{align}$$

Euler's integral representation for Gauss's hypergeometric function can be used to extend its domain outside of the disk, or outside the interval $[-1,1]$ if real variables are assumed. For each $\left(a,b,c,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that

$$c>b>0\land z<1\lor\left(c-a-b>0\land z=1\right),$$

we have

$${_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;z\right)}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(b,c-b\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{b-1}\left(1-t\right)^{c-b-1}}{\left(1-zt\right)^{a}}.$$

Also, it follows from Euler's integration formula for higher order hypergeometric functions that for each $\left(a,b,c,p,q,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{6}$ such that $0<a\land0<b\land0<p\land0<c<q\land-1<z<1$,

$${_3F_2}{\left(a,b,c;p,q;z\right)}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(c,q-c\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{c-1}\left(1-t\right)^{q-c-1}\,{_2F_1}{\left(a,b;p;zt\right)}.$$

Euler's hypergeometric transformation formula states

$${_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;z\right)}=\left(1-z\right)^{c-a-b}\,{_2F_1}{\left(c-a,c-b;c;z\right)};~~~\small{z<1\land0<a<c\land0<b<c}.$$

Lastly (and most obscurely), we will be needing the following [quadratic transformation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/02/10/0020/): for all $\left(a,b,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $0<a\land0<b\land0<z<1$,

$$\begin{align}
{_2F_1}{\left(a,b;\frac{a+b+1}{2};z\right)}
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2};\frac12;\left(2z-1\right)^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(2z-1\right)\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{b+1}{2};\frac32;\left(2z-1\right)^{2}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

### Actual Answer:

Given fixed but arbitrary $\left(n,\rho\right)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge3}\times\left(-1,1\right)$, define the function $g{\left(n,\rho;\cdot\right)}:\left(-1,1\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the hypergeometric expression

$$g{\left(n,\rho;r\right)}:=\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}}{\left(1-\rho r\right)^{n-\frac32}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac12,\frac12;n-\frac12;\frac{1+\rho r}{2}\right)}.$$

Then, define the function $G:\mathbb{Z}_{\ge3}\times\left(-1,1\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$G{\left(n,\rho\right)}:=\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}r\,g{\left(n,\rho;r\right)}.$$

Using Euler's transformation we find that for $x<1\land1<n$,

$${_2F_1}{\left(\frac12,\frac12;n-\frac12;\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}=\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)^{n-\frac32}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n-1,n-1;n-\frac12;\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}.$$

Then, using the quadratic transformation referenced above we find that for $\left(n,x\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $1<n\land-1<x<1$,

$$\begin{align}
{_2F_1}{\left(n-1,n-1;n-\frac12;\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(n-\frac12\right)}}{\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\right]^{2}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;x^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2x\,\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(n-\frac12\right)}}{\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}\right]^{2}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2};\frac32;x^{2}\right)}\\
\end{align}$$

or

$$\begin{align}
\frac{{_2F_1}{\left(n-1,n-1;n-\frac12;\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}
&=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;x^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(n-1\right)x}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2};\frac32;x^{2}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

We can then decompose $g$ into even and odd components with respect to $r$ as

$$\begin{align}
g{\left(n,\rho;r\right)}
&=\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}}{\left(1-\rho r\right)^{n-\frac32}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac12,\frac12;n-\frac12;\frac{1+\rho r}{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}}{\left(1-\rho r\right)^{n-\frac32}}\,\left(\frac{1-\rho r}{2}\right)^{n-\frac32}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n-1,n-1;n-\frac12;\frac{1+\rho r}{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}}{2^{n-\frac32}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n-1,n-1;n-\frac12;\frac{1+\rho r}{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}}{2^{n-\frac32}}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;\rho^{2}r^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}}{2^{n-\frac32}}\cdot\frac{2\left(n-1\right)\rho r\,\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2};\frac32;\rho^{2}r^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;\rho^{2}r^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\rho\left(n-1\right)\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}}\,r\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2};\frac32;\rho^{2}r^{2}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

This decomposition is particularly helpful here since the interval of integration is centered at zero. For the integral $G$, we obtain we obtain the closed-form expression

$$\begin{align}
G{\left(n,\rho\right)}
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}r\,g{\left(n,\rho;r\right)}\\
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}r\,\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;\rho^{2}r^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}r\,\frac{2\rho\left(n-1\right)\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}}\,r\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2};\frac32;\rho^{2}r^{2}\right)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}r\,\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;\rho^{2}r^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{2\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}r\,\left(1-r^{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;\rho^{2}r^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{-\frac12}\left(1-t\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;\rho^{2}t\right)};~~~\small{\left[r=\sqrt{t}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{\frac12-1}\left(1-t\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}-\frac12-1}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac12;\rho^{2}t\right)}\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,\frac{n}{2}-1\right)}\,{_3F_2}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2},\frac12;\frac12,\frac{n-1}{2};\rho^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,\frac{n}{2}-1\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2};\frac{n-1}{2};\rho^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,\frac{n}{2}-1\right)}}{2^{n-\frac32}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)}}\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-2)}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, this can be further simplified to

$$\begin{align}
G{\left(n,\rho\right)}
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-2)}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,n-\frac12\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-2)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(n-\frac12\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(n\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-2)}\cdot\frac{\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\right]^{2}\,\Gamma{\left(2n-1\right)}}{2^{2n-2}\,\left[\Gamma{\left(n\right)}\right]^{2}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-2)}\cdot\frac{\pi\,\left(2n-2\right)!}{4^{n-1}\,\left[\left(n-1\right)!\right]^{2}}\\
&=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-2)}\cdot\frac{\binom{2n-2}{n-1}}{4^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{(n-1)}{(n-2)}\cdot\frac{\pi\,2^{\frac52-2n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

I really wasn't expecting this integral to have a closed-form when I started. Very interesting problem!

---